# What is co_names?

Tags: python, documentation, cpython

The [description](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) for `co_names` in the inspect module reads:

> tuple of names of local variables

However in practice it appears that `co_names` is a tuple of global variable names while `co_varnames` is a tuple of local variable names (and argument names). For example:

```
a = 1

def f(b):
    c = a + b

print(f.__code__.co_varnames)  # prints ('b', 'c')
print(f.__code__.co_names)     # prints ('a',)
```

Furthermore in the docs for the `dis` module many instruction descriptions imply that `co_names` contains names of global variables. For example the `LOAD_GLOBAL` [description](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_GLOBAL) reads:

> Loads the global named co_names[namei] onto the stack.

Am I misunderstanding something here? Does `co_names` really contain "names of local variables"?

### **Edit 07/17/2017**

As mentioned in the comments/answers this appears to be a documentation error. Bug issue filed [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue30951).

### **Edit 07/22/2017**

[Pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/2743) to fix this documentation error approved and waiting to be merged.

### **Edit 06/06/2022**

[Pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/2743) was merged 09/24/2021.

Comment: Sounds like a documentation error to me.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a doc bug, might be worth filing it on http://bugs.python.org/, although should probably check the source first

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f9169ce6b48c7cc7cc62d9eb5e4ee1ac7066d14b/Lib/inspect.py#L1396

Comment: @Chris_Rands great find - thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As other's have already said, this seems to be **a documentation error**. The [documentation for code objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#index-55) clearly contradicts the [documentation for `inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html#types-and-members):

> `co_varnames` is **a tuple containing the names of the local variables** (starting with the argument names); [...] `co_names` is a **tuple containing the names used by the bytecode**;

Also, accessing the attributes `co_names` and `co_varnames` of code objects conflicts with what was stated in `inspect`:

```
>>> def f():
...     a = 1
...     b = 2
... 
>>> f.__code__.co_names
()
>>> f.__code__.co_varnames
('a', 'b')
```

Furthermore, comments in the source code for [CPython's compiler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/36ff451ebae41f09560bff582c95946474d898f8/Python/compile.c#L116) explicitly mention that `co_varnames` is for local variables:

```
PyObject *u_names;     /* all names */
PyObject *u_varnames; /* local variables */
```

The reason you don't see `co_varnames` is because the above code is initializing attributes for the *compiler object* that Python uses to compile code. [`u_names` and `u_varnames` are both later passed into `PyCode_New`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/compile.c#L5339) - the constructor for CPython code objects:

```
names = dict_keys_inorder(c->u->u_names, 0);
varnames = dict_keys_inorder(c->u->u_varnames, 0);

...

co = PyCode_New(..., names, varnames, ... );
```

And [`PyCode_New` assigns `names` and `varnames` to the `co_names` and `co_varnames` attributes respectively](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/codeobject.c#L190):

```
Py_INCREF(names);
co->co_names = names;
Py_INCREF(varnames);
co->co_varnames = varnames;
```

---

If you already have not, I suggest filling out a bug report at [bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/) to let the Python development team know about this inconsistency in the documentation.

Comment: @Alex Great. That's good to know. I'll check back up on the report later and update my answer if anything relevant surfaces.

Comment: I think we are all agreed that `co_names` does not contain the local variables as documented, but it obviously does not match the contents of the `globals()` `dict` either and `a = 2; f = lambda: None; print(f.__code__.co_names)` results in an empty tuple for example @Alex

Comment: @Chris_Rands Agreed. As far as I can tell it contains the names of global variables used in the code object... Just as `co_freevars` only contains the names of free variables that are actually used in closures.

Comment: I guess this was seen in the PR - but we can note here too that it contains more than just the names of globals - if you use a dotted path like "pd.cut.foo" then "pd", "cut", "foo" are all included as separate names.