# Why do imports behind `if False` generate local variables?

Tags: python, import, scope

The following code works as expected:

```py
from os import name

def function():
    # if False:
    #     from os import name
    print(name)

function()
```

However, when uncommenting the `if False` block, the code stops working:

> UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable `name` where it is not associated with a value

I wonder why that is. I have since found https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/79250#issuecomment-1093803068 which says that this is "documented behavior" - I wonder *where* this is documented, though.

Comment: If a function assigns to a name, then that name is assumed to be a local variable, even if there is a global one of the same name.  This is true even if the assignment never actually executes.  Python "magically knows" that the function is **theoretically capable** of assigning that name, therefore it is treated as local.

Comment: It's not that magical; names are marked as local during code generation, which doesn't concern itself with whether a particular assignment (or import) is reachable.

Comment: Without the assignment, `name` is a *free* variable, looked up in the closest enclosing scope (which in this case is the global scope).

Comment: @JohnGordon actually, I decided to use the disassembler and confirmed that _no assignment_ actually happens (i.e. no `STORE_FAST` bytecode instructions gets generated - actually the whole `if False` block gets `NOP`ed out), what actually happens is that names with local assignments will get put into `co_varnames` at an even earlier stage - not exactly magic.  I even had to correct my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior regarding `UnboundLocalError` is documented most clearly under the official documentation in the Programming FAQ section, under the heading [why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value).  The full behavior regarding this is broadly covered under the ["naming and binding"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) section under "execution model" in the [The Python Language Reference manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html).  Specifically, the  following paragraph in section 4.2.2. Resolution of names, fully describes the issue at hand:

> When a name is not found at all, a `NameError` exception is raised. If the current scope is a function scope, and the name refers to a local variable that has not yet been bound to a value at the point where the name is used, an `UnboundLocalError` exception is raised.

As an import inside a function scope (even if hasn't happened yet) will provide an assignment under `name`, resulting in local variable `name`, and given that it isn't bounded where it gets used (via `print`), the `UnboundLocalError` will be the result.

As for the "why" - Python does not fully ignore unreachable branches, all code behind `if False` blocks are considered by the interpreter, so any assignments to some name within a function block, even if "unreachable", will render the given name a valid local variable (specifically, while the generated bytecode as seen by the disassembler may `NOP` out that block, all assignments to some names within will render all those names as entries in [`co_varnames`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147260/what-is-co-names)).

As an aside, the FAQ entry has been present [since Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) (or perhaps even earlier).